# How do you set the 'T' bit?

Tags: shell, permissions

My TeX Live installation has a file called `.texlive2015` and was originally set to `drwx------T`. I changed it, and I want to change it back, but I can't get the 'T' back. How do I get it back?

Comment: The `t` bit on a directory causes files created in it to be deletable by their owners instead of by the owner of the directory. For a directory that's only writable by its owner, that makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 'T' indicates the sticky bit. You can use something like `chmod a+t` to set it.

Answer (score 13):

The `T` flag is a special version of the expected `t`. Usually `t` sits with execute `x`, but if the execute bit is not set for *others* then the `t` is flagged up as a capital.

```
touch f
chmod u=rwx,go=rx f    # "-rwxr-xr-x 1 roaima 0 Sep 10 23:13 f"
chmod +t f             # "-rwxr-xr-t 1 roaima 0 Sep 10 23:13 f"
chmod o-x f            # "-rwxr-xr-T 1 roaima 0 Sep 10 23:13 f"

chmod u=rwx,go=,+t f   # "-rwx-----T 1 roaima 0 Sep 10 23:13 f"
```

Comment: This one is good too. I just used the one below.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the permission bit:

`chmod 1700 f`

The first bit `1` represents the restricted deletion flag or sticky bit and shows on the execute permission bit for all users as `t`

The following number `7`, octal is `111`, represents owner’s **read write execute** permission bit, which shows `rwx`

The following number `00`, represents group and world **read write execute** permission bit, which shows `- - - - - -`

Comment: The danger of using the octal representations is if you use `-R` and remove the wrong permission from directories suddenly you can't traverse them no matter WHO you are. The `chmod -R a-wx,og+rw` syntax is safer in this case.